# What is correct way to start new version of the existing website?

Tags: version

Thanks for your attention to my post! I would appreciate any help.

I am newbie to the whole thing of the web development. I have existing website that runs on magento 1.7. At this moment, I would like to make a new version of my website. I also want that the new version would be developed on live server, not on a local machine.

I would like that the current version of the website will be running while I will work on the new version and then, when work will be done, I want to switch to the new version.

What would be correct way to do that? What should be my steps?

My web hosting is Virtual Private Server that runs CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty concerns migration of the existing data. The easiest way to proceed in a situation like this (if it is possible and desired) is to develop the new site under the exact same architecture (Magento in your case), with an import of the actual data. You need of course to protect the new website under development from any public access. All development can then be done in this place until everything is satisfying. The day you are ready to go live, you can quickly interrupt the real site with a maintenance message, and migrate the data to the new site. The interruption will only be as long as the data migration. You also have to decide whether you will: 1) replace your website by changing all the files on the original server (except the "maintenance message index page" that will stay till the end and be the only accessible file with a temporary redirect) or 2) point to another server where your new setup is placed by changing the DNS (in which case there could be a small delay for DNS propagation, although this is way quicker nowadays than it used to be about 10 years ago).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I do not care about existing data.

Comment: Well then it is even easier : just do as I said, but install the new website on a 2nd server and do a DNS switch on the day you want to make it live (and block access to the old one just during DNS propagation). That is much easier.

Comment: What do you mean, saying "install website on a 2nd server"? I have only one VPS.

Comment: I see. The easiest is usually to have two different IPs when switching between two versions because it makes it very simple, being just a DNS switch. I have a VPS Ubuntu with Plesk and if I remember well, it is very easy to migrate files from one domain inside the VPS to another. So your solution could be this (develop on a domain in your VPS and transfer when ready, after backing up old site + deleting all files). Yet to be honest, it does not sound as clean as what I usually do : develop on another server with another IP and then just switch the DNS on the launch day.

Comment: Thank you barakadam. I am going use two platform in my future

Comment: Thank you barakadam. New IP address is going to cost me something. Probably, I am not going to go this direction. I am going, also, use two platform in my future version of the website: Joomla and Magento wrapped inside Joomla. I read somewhere that I can set a new sub domain under existing and develop new version on this sub domain. When work on new version will be done I can move new version in the root. But, I still have concern if this kind of move will cause some problem with data bases of the new version setup?

Comment: Yes you can do this. But if you take the example of WordPress, when you do something like this, you have to modify the database before changing domains by replacing "http://subdomain.domain.com/" with "http://domain.com" everywhere. I suppose the same difficulty arises with Joomla and Magento.